# Mobile browsers cant display a specific image

Tags: html, css, browser

On desktop browsers, an image shows up fine, including when I test responsivity. It works on all browsers but on any mobile browser, the image will be a box wireframe with its alt text.

If you visit [tyedwithlove.com](https://tyedwithlove.com), the logo image in the nav and footer displays fine on any desktop browser and size but does not on any mobile browser. I tried testing saving the image by holding on it on mobile, and it said I had no internet connection. Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Comment: It will be difficult to help you if you don't show your code.

Comment: It could be that you lost your internet connection. Silly remarks aside, the amount of information you're giving us here can't help us tell if this is a programming error, a file format compatibility issue or even a hardware problem.

Comment: From my nokia 8 and any mobile emulator I tried the logo image from the footer displays just fine. But the TYED image from the nav is not showing if width is under 850px no matter what. I'm guessing this is due to some media queries.

Comment: Code is available through inspect element, nothing else was used. It is the TYED image that does mobile browsers cant access whatsoever for some reason.